# How to send formatted emails using AWS SES with terraform scripts

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, java-8, terraform, amazon-ses

I am working on a java application in which I need to send email whenever user created a change request from UI. I am using AWS SES for sending emails.
 I have created a json template file(below)

```
{
  "Template": {
    "TemplateName": "EmailNotification",
    "SubjectPart": "Email regarding your change request",
    "HtmlPart": "<br>Be, informed that your change request is created.<br> Details of the operation:<br> TimeStamp: {{timestamp}}<br> User: {{user}}<br> User Id: {{userId}}<br>"
  }
}
```

Now I want to create a new terraform with a resource named "email" and load the content of this json file inside that resource. For that I can use something like this(below)

```
resource "xxxxx" "email" {
  input     = templatefile("${path.module}/input.json.tmpl",
}
```

Can somebody please help me in identifying which resource should I need to use(in place of xxxxx) and how to create a terraform from scratch with only this single resource.

Edit- Update I have removed json file as resource `aws_ses_template` doesn't support `input` argument. Now, I am able to create theresource but getting error while defining policy. Below is my terraform

```
policy = <<EOF
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action":[
            "ses:SendEmail",
            "ses:SendTemplatedEmail",
            "ses:SendRawEmail",
            "ses:SendBulkTemplatedEmail"
        ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
EOF

resource "aws_ses_template" "emailNotification" {
  name        = "emailNotification"
  subject     = "Email regarding your change request"
  html        = "<br>Be, informed that your change request is created.<br> Details of the operation:<br> TimeStamp: {{timestamp}}<br> User: {{user}}<br> User Id: {{userId}}<br>"
}
```

But, I am getting an error(below) for this policy

```
Error: Unsupported argument
        on email_notification.tf line 1:
            1: policy = <<EOF 
    An argument named "policy" is not expected here.
```

Which resource should I use where I can put this policy

Comment: Can you not define the email template in the SES resource?

Comment: Here it is: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ses_template.

Comment: @MarkoE Thank you but I got a comment to read the file inside resource. So now resource name should be aws_ses_template and input tag will load the content but how to create a terraform which contains only this single resource.

Comment: Why? What is that single resource supposed to do? Does it need to be a file on a local file system? It's unclear.

Comment: It is just for separation. In future there will be many other resources for different email templated so it is better to create a separate terraform from the beginning